# Keypair is smaller than expected

Tags: .net, public-key-encryption

This C# code (running against .NET 4.5):

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(rsa.KeySize);
            Console.WriteLine(rsa.ExportCspBlob(true).Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Produces this output:

```
1024
596
```

Why is the resulting key blob about half of the requested key size?  How could it be any less than the keysize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1024 is bits, 596 is bytes, or 4768 bits.

Comment: Don't be hard on yourself, I've done the *exact* same thing :)

Comment: Any idea why it takes 4768 bits to represent a 1024-bit key?